# Facebook App Permissions Leads to Blank Page

Tags: php, facebook

I've been using PHP to make websites for a while, and thought it'd be fun to try my hand at making a Facebook app.

Everything was going smoothly until the last issue.  For some reason, when the user clicks on the link to grant extended permissions, they are shown a blank page that has the Facebook logo and nothing more:

`<a href = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://x.com/next.php&scope=offline_access,read_stream,user_groups" > <img src ="images/analyze.png"> </a>`

This was not a problem earlier in development.  I have no idea why this is happening, and am fairly sure earlier on, it was not happening (when I just started making the app, the extended permissions page seemed to work fine)

Any thoughts?  Would greatly appreciate it.  If more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Can you check with firebug (net tab) for any unsuccessful requests, also check if the user is already granted you these permissions and finally have you tried the [php-sdk](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not allowed to open facebook in an iframe, if I remember right `target="_top"` can fix that:

```
<a href = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://x.com/next.php&scope=offline_access,read_stream,user_groups" target="_top"> <img src ="images/analyze.png"> </a>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. this works in that the application then runs fine - the only problem is that it then loses the Facebook frame (so you just see a blank page) –

Comment: Yep it loses the iframe this is why you need to set the redirect_uri to something like apps.facebook.com/yourapp/next.php.

Comment: Gosh, that's helpful.  Thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: please tag the answer as solution if your problem got solved. :)